# vSphere Essentials Plus kit licensing issue

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I just received the above license from VMware for one of my customers. The VCA 6.7 appliance and the two ESXi hosts were running in evaluation mode. I had no issues to enter the license for the VCA appliance, but when trying to license one of the hosts, I get the following message:

> The license does not support some of the features that are currently
> in use by the licensed assets.
>
> -vSphere FT

I have no such feature enabled in any virtual machine, and as far as I know this is not a Cluster or Host level thing, it is just a VM level feature.

I also tried to migrate any virtual machine away from the host, and remove the host from the cluster, but nothing changes.

[image: licensing error]

I also opened a ticket with them and will be glad to share their solution later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a post on a third party forum that pointed my attention to the networking configuration of the ESXi host VMkernel ports. Indeed, in Host > Configure > Networking > Virtual Switches, I found that one of the host's VMkernel ports had Fault Tolerance logging enabled.

[image: Disable FT logging to fix this issue]

Once I disabled it the license was accepted, with the multiple warnings I expected due to Enterprise features becoming unavailable.